# Find row that has lowest average for any given column set

Tags: google-sheets

I'd like to think that I'm no longer a beginner Spreadsheet user, however, every now and then I get stuck on one of the challenges I face. In the images below I've removed some decimals to anonymize the data but most values look similar to this: 0.0546

**Question**: I want to feed the formula a set of columns, for example, 4 and 13. Now I want it to return the row with:

a) values in all columns

b) the lowest average
I also need both the values, the column letter as well as the average value.

[Dataset with two examples](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WZpVq.png)
[image: Dataset with two examples]

Additional information, in the future more rows, can be added. They will contain anything between one (like; a) and 26 (like; b & c) values. I can request a row and average from a column set with the same, anywhere from 1 to 26 columns.

If it proves too difficult to get both steps I also figured I could enter like 99999 in the empty cells so that the average will always be higher if there's no value.

Thanks in advance! Let me know if you require additional information

Comment: pls share a copy of your sheet with example of desired result

Comment: Like this? https://1drv.ms/x/s!AtXsBO7HAcL1gQE4fsiafKIVEBWE?e=PD1hTa Maybe I didn't understand completely